# Multinomial Pmf Definition Explanation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I understand that the multinomial distribution is a generalization of the binomial distribution and it's probability mass function can be used to determine the probability of each bin achieving a certain number of successes. I've included the pmf below

$$p(n_1, \ldots, n_2) = {n \choose n_1 \cdots n_r}\  p_1^{n_1} p_2^{n_2} \cdots p_r^{n_r}$$

where $ {n \choose n_1 \cdots n_r} = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_r!}$

What I'm confused about is why it couldn't be defined in a way much like the binomial distribution. That is, why don't we include the full sequence of successes and failures like we do in the binomial case? For example:

$$p(n_1, \ldots, n_2) = {n \choose n_1 \cdots n_r}\  p_1^{n_1} p_2^{n_2} \cdots p_r^{n_r} (1 - p_1)^{n - n_1} (1 - p_2)^{n - n_2} \cdots (1 - p_r)^{n - n_r}$$

Comment: In the binomial, let $p_1$ be the probability of success and $p_2=1-p_1$ be the probability of failure. Then the probability of $n_1$ successes and $n_2=n-n_1$ failures is $\binom{n}{n_1,n_2}p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}$.  Same formula.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks! It's like success and failure are their own bins. I now have a better understanding of why it's called a generalization of the binomial. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. A full answer would explain why the probability of $n_1$ in Bin 1, $n_2$ in Bin 2, and so on to $n_r$ in Bin $r$ is what it is.

Comment: But aren't the probabilities given for each of the bins? I can see that since the probabilities must sum to 1 they are connected. For example, the probabilities for $r$ bins I think would be $(p_1, (1 - (p_1 + p_3 + \cdots + p_r))\ , (1 - (p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_r))\ , ...)$ Is this what you mean?

Comment: That is correct. But since $p_1+p_2+\cdot +p_r=1$, we have that your second term turns out to be equal to $p_2$, the third term is equal to $p_3$, and so on.

Comment: Haha wow! Can't believe I didn't see that. I now understand the formula even better. Thanks again